# Регистрация на сайте

Tags: asp.net, html, javascript

Как сделать регистрацию на сайте, через аккаунты в vkontakte и facebook
(как, например, на этом сайте)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://vkontakte.ru/developers.php?o=-17680044&p=Open%20API

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Answer (score 2):

Если неохота вникать в тонкости API каждой конкретной системы можно легко встроить на сайт систему единой идентификации, например, [Loginza](http://loginza.ru/). Кроме простоты использования, достоинство таких систем в том, что вам не нужно следить за изменениями API конкретных порталов, а также вы получаете автоматическую поддержку практически любой новой крупной системы идентификации.